# Can I embed a number in binary instead of hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I write binary number in code without using

```
Convert.ToInt16("00001000", 2);
```

I want it to be very fast, I don't want to read number from string.
Is there any faster way?

Comment: You mean you want something like `int i = 00001000b;` or `0b00001000`?

Comment: what format do you have the binary number in before doing the conversion?

Comment: C# doesn't support binary literals. You need to do the conversion yourself. Or how about writing this bit in IronPython? ;)

Comment: You seriously think the overhead from `Convert.ToInt16` is ever going to matter the slightest bit?

Comment: @Hooch: then use the conversion to initialise a static readonly field so it is only done once (per AppDomain). In practice binary <-> hex conversion is trivial.

Comment: @Hooch - Why do you feel it will make a difference? I can tell you I am reading a 48-bit number, converting the integer into string, then changing the string back into a number, and I have no speed problems which would be a great deal slower then Convert.ToInt16. The data in question is being recieved every 1ms.

Comment: How in the *world* is this a bottleneck in your application? What possible reason would you have to be doing this several hundred thousand times in a loop?

Comment: @Code - When did he say how often he was doing this?

Comment: @Ramhound: He's saying `How can I write binary number in code...` which leads me to believe that those are hardcoded, therefor he should initialise a variable with it, and not do it every few cycles if he needs that more then ones.

Comment: @Ramhound: The implication was that the only possible way that a call to `Convert.ToInt16` could be a bottleneck that was worth optimizing in a program was if you were doing it several hundred thousand times in a loop. Since he *didn't* say that, any answer to this question is specious at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C# Language Specification:

> 2.4.4.2 Integer literals
>
> Integer literals are used to write
>   values of types int, uint, long, and
>   ulong. Integer literals have two
>   possible forms: decimal and
>   hexadecimal.

You can do it your way:

```
Convert.ToInt16("00001000", 2);
```

Or representing the number in hex format for example using the `0x` prefix, as in:

```
0x8
```

I am not aware of any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the number in hexadecimal: `0x8`.
[Google Calculator](http://www.google.com/search?q=0b00001000+in+hex) can convert between bases.

Comment: Ahm, could you please extend the last sentence...it always gives me the creeps if I see Google-Links without further explanations (useful in this case, I agree, but please describe it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, for the sake of avoiding any silly errors, when I define a "flags" enum I'll use the bit-shift operator to specify the values and just let the compiler figure it out.  For example:

```
[Flags]
enum FlagsEnum
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1 << 0,
    Two = 1 << 1,
    Four = 1 << 2,
    Eight = 1 << 3,
    Sixteen = 1 << 4,
    ThirtyTwo = 1 << 5,
    SixtyFour = 1 << 6,
    OneHundredTwentyEight = 1 << 7,
    // etc.
}
```

I find this style easier to maintain when I inevitably reorder and add/remove values from my enum.

So in your case, you could specify your binary value "00001000" as `(1 << 3)`.  If you had something more complicated, though, like "00101000", then this wouldn't work too well; you *could* do something like `(1 << 5) | (1 << 3)`, but for that case I would just specify the value in hex.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a special class for this

```
public static class B
{
    public static readonly V _0000 = 0x0;
    public static readonly V _0001 = 0x1;
    public static readonly V _0010 = 0x2;
    public static readonly V _0011 = 0x3;
    public static readonly V _0100 = 0x4;
    public static readonly V _0101 = 0x5;
    public static readonly V _0110 = 0x6;
    public static readonly V _0111 = 0x7;

    public static readonly V _1000 = 0x8;
    public static readonly V _1001 = 0x9;
    public static readonly V _1010 = 0xA;
    public static readonly V _1011 = 0xB;
    public static readonly V _1100 = 0xC;
    public static readonly V _1101 = 0xD;
    public static readonly V _1110 = 0xE;
    public static readonly V _1111 = 0xF;

    public struct V
    {
        ulong Value;

        public V(ulong value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        private V Shift(ulong value)
        {
            return new V((this.Value << 4) + value);
        }

        public V _0000 { get { return this.Shift(0x0); } }
        public V _0001 { get { return this.Shift(0x1); } }
        public V _0010 { get { return this.Shift(0x2); } }
        public V _0011 { get { return this.Shift(0x3); } }
        public V _0100 { get { return this.Shift(0x4); } }
        public V _0101 { get { return this.Shift(0x5); } }
        public V _0110 { get { return this.Shift(0x6); } }
        public V _0111 { get { return this.Shift(0x7); } }

        public V _1000 { get { return this.Shift(0x8); } }
        public V _1001 { get { return this.Shift(0x9); } }
        public V _1010 { get { return this.Shift(0xA); } }
        public V _1011 { get { return this.Shift(0xB); } }
        public V _1100 { get { return this.Shift(0xC); } }
        public V _1101 { get { return this.Shift(0xD); } }
        public V _1110 { get { return this.Shift(0xE); } }
        public V _1111 { get { return this.Shift(0xF); } }

        static public implicit operator V(ulong value)
        {
            return new V(value);
        }

        static public implicit operator ulong(V this_)
        {
            return this_.Value;
        }

        static public implicit operator uint(V this_)
        {
            return (uint)this_.Value;
        }

        static public implicit operator ushort(V this_)
        {
            return (ushort)this_.Value;
        }

        static public implicit operator byte(V this_)
        {
            return (byte)this_.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
byte x = B._0010._0011;
ushort y = B._1001._0011._1111._0000;
uint z = B._1001._0011._1111._1000._0011;
ulong d = B._1001._0011._1111._1000._0011._0001;
```

Implemented in [CityLizard Framework (CityLizard.Binary.dll)](http://citylizard.codeplex.com/).